# Unable to locate the installed graph-tool package in Python

Tags: python, graph-tool

I spent 1 hr 30mins to install graph-tool package. Installation declared that it was successful. When I tried to import it says "no module by name graph_tool..." I guess I am missing the path or link to this module. How to link or import?

Also, when I ran the command "pip freeze" it does not show the graph_tool package installed. Please help to resolve these problems. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure it isn't listed under another name?

Comment: means? any other choices?

Comment: How did you (try to) install the package? What command(s) etc?

Comment: sudo port install py-graph-tool

Comment: I used: > port contents py-graph-tool   (This command gives me the following status report) - 
Port py-graph-tool contains:
  /opt/local/share/doc/py-graph-tool/README

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the system's python, whereas graph-tool was installed for macport's python. You should call the interpreter corresponding to macport's version, usually `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

Python modules have been installed but the site-packages may not be
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run like this:

```
mkdir -p /Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

In my case it's the homebrew site-packages, but may not yours